# Hidding the text is not working in mozilla (Can i get alternative)

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am writting css as

```
.hidetext { -webkit-text-security: disc; }
```

To showing in table by hidding this text using following code.

```
<tr><td>Ramp : </td><td class="hidetext"><?php echo $_POST["uma"] ?></td></tr>
```

This is working on chrome it not working on mozilla.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is **non-standard** and is **not on a standards track.** Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be **large incompatibilities between implementations** and the behavior may change in the future.

**In short, Firefox does not support it**.

[image]

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-security

However, there is a package that aims to provide Cross-browser alternative to `-webkit-text-security`

https://github.com/noppa/text-security

Comment: Can i get any alternative for this

Answer (score 0):

Any css property beginning with `-webkit-` is only supported by chromium/chrome based browsers such as Chrome, Opera, Edge and so on. But Firefox is not one of them, hence it does not work.